# Apache Axis2 HTTPException error

Tags: apache, soap, apache-axis, apache-commons-httpclient, httpexception

I'm trying to connect to an HTTPS Axis2 SOAP source. It seems that I have done all the steps and imported all dependencies to my classpath, still it will give me an ClassDefNotFound HTTPException.

[image: Classpath]

```
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpException
Exception has been occurred, error message: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpException
stack trace:

    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:699)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:123)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:857)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:144)
    at com.ericsson.mh.soapaxis.service.TRServiceStub.<init>(TRServiceStub.java:879)
    at com.ericsson.mh.soapaxis.service.TRServiceStub.<init>(TRServiceStub.java:865)
    at com.ericsson.mh.soapaxis.service.TRServiceStub.<init>(TRServiceStub.java:914)
    at com.ericsson.mh.soapaxis.client.TRClientUserGuideExample.main(TRClientUserGuideExample.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:684)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

Anyone have the slightest idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Import all the jars that you found in the axis2 source archive.